# How to Create Movable Background with Cocos

Tags: iphone, background, cocos2d-iphone

If anyone can help me I would be really really appreciated because Could not find any clear solution anywhere about this issue. I'm just a beginner with Cocos2d and iPhone and want to create a background navigable sliding up and down. More like angry birds(the background follows the birds once they are thrown as well as user can wonder around on the background with sliding). According from what I have gathered only solution seem using tile map. But do I have to use tile map? Can I put one big image and use touch start function. If I can, I certainly do not know how to do it.

Can you please give a starting point or example code of simple work. This has been bothering me for weeks. Please help because I am almost desperate.

PS: I have seen the example of automatically sliding background which created with an image but that's not exactly what I want. Another good example of want I exactly want can be the game "zombie takeover".

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to know the CCLayer, CCSprite. Theses are very common classes in cocos2D.
2. You have to know how to enable touch, and you also have to know some methods like ccTouchesBegan.
3. The relationship of anchor point & position.
4. You can also find some sample in cocos2d-x's source code, in "test" folder.
5. Just go ahead then you will know how to do it natually.